Why is there so much controversy that biblical days were counted inclusively?
There is more than enough evidence that biblical days were counted inclusively yet there are many that dispute this.
https://www.wednesdaycrucifixion.com/inclusive-reckoning.html
Here are some proofs of inclusive counting from the web page above:
1, The clearest Biblical demonstration of inclusive counting is in the New Testament (see Acts 10:30 where a period of 72 hours is reckoned as “four days ago,” not “three”), but an Old Testament example is in 2 Kings 18:9-10.
2.The battle of Samaria lasted from the fourth to the sixth year of Hezekiah, which is equated with the The siege seventh to the ninth year of Hoshea, and yet the city is said to have been taken “at the end of three years.” In modern usage we would say two years, by straight subtraction. Obviously the Bible writer reckoned inclusively (years four, five, and six totaling three years).

A Hebrew boy was circumcised when “eight days old” (Genesis 17:12), that is, “in the eighth day” (Levites 12:3). Similarly Luke speaks of circumcision “on the eighth day” or “when eight days were accomplished” (Luke 1:59; 2:21). Evidently “when eight days were accomplished” (or “at the end of eight days,” RSV) does not mean eight full days from the date of birth, but eight inclusive.

4.Jeroboam II of Israel succeeded his father Jehoash in the 15th year of Amaziah of Judah (2 Kings 14:23), and Amaziah “lived after the death of Jehoash … of Israel fifteen years” (2 Kings 14:17). A modern reader would mentally add 15 to 15, reaching Amaziah’s 30th year, yet Amaziah reigned only 29 years (verse 2). Inclusive reckoning is again the most logical explanation, since 15 years, inclusive, from the 15th year is the 29th, in which he evidently died.
5.There are other examples. When, at the death of Solomon, Rehoboam was petitioned to lighten the tax burden, he told the people to depart “for three days” (1 Kings 12:5) and then return for his decision “after three days” (2 Chronicles 10:5). They came “the third day, as the king had appointed, saying, Come to me again the third day” (1 Kings 12:12; cf. 2 Chronicles 10:12).

Jesus said in Luke 13:32 And he said unto them, Go ye, and tell that fox, Behold, I cast out devils, and I do cures to day and to morrow, and the third day I shall be perfected.

Exodus 19:10-11 And the LORD said unto Moses, Go unto the people, and sanctify them to day and to morrow, and let them wash their clothes, 11 And be ready against the third day: for the third day the LORD will come down in the sight of all the people upon mount Sinai.

Esther asked the Jews of Shushan to fast, and by implication, to pray, for her before she went in to the king unbidden, and then she approached the king “on the third day” (Esther 4:16; 5:1). Obviously a period of “three days” ended on the third day, not after the completion of the three days, as we would reckon it.


9.The Pharisees did not call a high day “the Sabbath”. They called it “a Sabbath”. All days
called “the Sabbath” in the New Testament (39 times in the Greek text) referred to the weekly Sabbath.

An Egyptian inscription recording the death of a priestess on the 4th day of the 12th month relates that her successor arrived on the 15th, “when 12 days had elapsed.” Today, we would say that when 12 days had elapsed after the 4th, the date would be the 16th.

The Greeks followed the same inclusive method. They called the Olympiad, or the four-year period between the Olympic Games, a pentaeteris (five-year period), and used other similar numerical terms

The Romans also, in common usage, reckoned inclusively; they had nundinae (from nonus, ninth), or market days, every ninth day, inclusive, actually every eight days, as indicated on ancient calendars by the letters, A through H.

Modern vestiges in the West are the phrase “eight days,” meaning a week in some European languages; I hope these help.

Also, read John 4. In that chapter Jesus meets the Samaritan woman whom gives a drink of water. In verse 40 says Jesus abode in her village for two days (John 4:40) and yet in John 4:43 it claims that Jesus departed after two days. I can prove elsewhere that "after three days" which appears in Mark three times in reference to Jesus's resurrection was equivalent to "the third day" in Matthew and Luke.

John 20:26 says, "after eight days" the disciples were again gathered in the room when Jesus appeared amongst them. Scholars claim "after eight days" was an expression meaning a week later (i.e. Sunday to Sunday). Again, inclusive counting.

It is important to note that Mark 8:31, 9:31, and 10:34 claim Jesus would rise "after three days". Yet, when you compare the same accounts in Matthew and Luke in a good Harmony of the Gospels you will see "after three days" is interchangeable with "the third day".

Here is a definition of day from the Jewish Encyclopedia. https://tinyurl.com/3xy5p3ve


Many of the above are culled from the website for inclusive counting. There is more than enough evidence that biblical days were counted inclusively yet there are many that dispute this.
https://www.wednesdaycrucifixion.com/inclusive-reckoning.html

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Overview
The controversy stems from the dating of the crucifixion and resurrection. The tradition of Good Friday and Easter Sunday means the time on the tomb was possibly as few as 26 hours. Regardless of the actual time, it is well short of the length of time needed for 3 days. To reconcile a 3-day period with a weekly calendar, Friday to Sunday, inclusive counting is invoked. Thus any part of a day would be counted as a day, Friday (1), Saturday (2), Sunday (3).
Inclusive counting also raises questions about what Jesus said:
Matthew 12:40

For as Jonah was three days and three nights in the belly of the great fish, so will the Son of Man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth.

In a comment Dottard explains the objection to what Jesus said:

This is an old chestnut and a minority view created by some who suffer from the hermeneutical equivalent of obsessive compulsive pedantry, AND who focus on a single text to the exclusion of all other data. I fully agree with your statement above; but these pedantic souls obsess over the "three days and three nights" - a single verse, Matt 12:40 and attempt to bend all the rest of the NT chronology to fit it.

Arguments Against Counting Inclusively
Before listing reasons against inclusive counting, I suggest considering the words of Jesus, either 3-days or 3-days and 3-nights, if they had been spoken from the cross. If, on Friday, Jesus had said from the cross, "I will rise from the dead in three days," would anyone have gone to the tomb as the Sabbath ended? Would anyone hearing "3-days" late Friday afternoon expect Jesus to rise from the dead a few hours after the Sabbath ended?
Biblical objections to inclusive counting:

The days in creation are counted as full days.
A day begins at sunset.
Sabbaths are always counted as full days.
The six days of work leading up to the Sabbath are counted as full days.
The annual Feast Days of Shavuot, Trumpets, and Atonement are observed as full days.
The 7-days of Unleavened Bread are observed as 7 full days.
The 7-days of Tabernacles are observed as full days.
The day following the 7-days of Tabernacles is observed as a full day.

Conclusion
Inclusive counting during the Feast of Unleavened Bread is most unlikely.
On one hand we must accept the Jewish people will eat unleavened bread for seven full days, and they will observe a full day of no work on the first day and the last day of the 7-day feast. However, despite the need to observe full days of no work and to count seven full days to observe the feast, these same people are going to count the days in the tomb differently?
There may be instances where people counted as they saw fit, but it seems unlikely there would be two ways of counting days while observing the 7-days Of Unleavened Bread, especially since this period included two full days of no work. Even if people some people did so, there is no evidence the Son of God approved or employed this practice.

@Dottard I discussed this (three days and  three nights" issue in detail with Revelation Lad. He quotes your "old chestnut" comment in another post and he and I ended up discussing the issue on Christian Forums online. Read it and see what you think/ https://www.christianforums.com/threads/the-crucifixion-not-friday.8296268/page-6
